# Why do people use signs in columns/rows of several kernels reversed?

Tags: computer-vision, kernel

I have observed that different citations/codes use signs in different (reversed) columns/rows for many kernels. Here is an example for Prewitt (but same for Sobel, Scharr, etc); in some cases is written such:

```
prewitt_v = np.array([[-1, 0, 1],
                      [-1, 0, 1],
                      [-1, 0, 1]])

prewitt_h = np.array([[-1, -1, -1],
                      [0, 0, 0],
                      [1, 1, 1]])
```

but in other cases as such:

```
prewitt_v = np.array([[1, 0, -1],
                      [1, 0, -1],
                      [1, 0, -1]])

prewitt_h = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                      [0, 0, 0],
                      [-1, -1, -1]])
```

What is the explanation for this inconsequency?